# Shared account / dual blogging in WordPress

Tags: admin, users, user-roles

I am running my own hosting and domain, with WordPress installed on it. I am planning on posting there regularly, once or twice a day.

However, a friend of mine would also like to contribute with his own blog posts. I'm wondering if there is a way to create a "guest" account on WordPress, with which he can post whenever and wherever he wants, but without granting him full admin rights (like deleting other posts, changing the theme structure, changing the admin's profile information, and so on).

**I though about two solutions:**

1. **The first one** is that he sends me his posts via e-mail and then I post them in my blog under his name. However, the main drawback of this alternative is that I need to be online/available, and his posts might not be uploaded whenever he wants.
2. **Second option** would be to buy another hosting+domain and share expenses (total price / 2). This, however, does not solve the problem about him being able to change the administrator's main password.

All in all: is it possible to create a "secondary"/"guest" account that he can use to write on the blog? This secondary account would have restricted access/limitations, such as those I mentioned earlier (not being able to delete other posts, changing admin's data/password, changing the main's theme structure, so on).

Hope this question is not too basic, I'm new to this beautiful WordPress world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is really very basic. If you are the admin, you can create new users and [asign them a role](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities). You could make your friend 'author', which would allow him to write and edit his own posts only, or make him an 'editor' if you also want him to edit other people's post.

Comment: Thanks @cjbj, as I can see from your answer this question was really basic. Hope it doesn't get too many downvotes. By the way, let's say I create a new "author" user. How would he log-in? Through the typical wordpress-login screen we admins see as well?

Comment: Yes, in the same way. He just would have less options in the backoffice.